# Unable to update state with Array of objects in RN

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state, setstate

I have a blank array in the `state` object. The array will contain some objects with key-value pair.

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, ScrollView, View, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, ListView, Switch, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';


export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});

    this.state = {
      TodoTextVal: '',
      todos: []
    }

    this.addTodo = this.addTodo.bind(this);
  }

  addTodo() {
    id++;
    let TodoTextVal = this.state.TodoTextVal;
    //let arrVal = {id: id, text: TodoTextVal, checked: false}
    //this.setState(prevState => ({todos : [...prevState.todos, arrVal]}));
    this.setState({
      todos: [
        ...this.state.todos,
        {id: id, text: TodoTextVal, checked: false}
      ], 
    })

  }

  toggle(id) {

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={{flexDirection: "row"}}>
          <TextInput
            onChangeText={(TodoTextVal) => this.setState({TodoTextVal})} 
            ref= {(el) => { this.TodoTextVal = el; }}
            style={[styles.input, {flex: 2} ]} 
            placeholder="Add Todo..."/>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.addTodo} title="+ Add" style={styles.button} >
            <Text>Add</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        <ListView 
          dataSource={this.ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.todos)}
          renderRow={(data) => <View><Text>{data}</Text></View>} />

      </View>
    );
  }
}

let id = 0
```

The problem here is `this.setState()` is not updating the state. I've tried both the method which you see in `addTodo()` that commented code too.

But both the methods are throwing an error with this message:

> Device: (96:380) Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React
>   child (found: object with keys {id, text, checked}).

Comment: How you are using `todos` array, can you please share some code?

Comment: No, I am not using it yet. How can I use this until it is updated? First I wanna set the state.

Comment: Please share the code of `render` method

Comment: The error you are providing is mostly related to how you render your component, it would be nice if you can share it

Comment: I have updated my code. Please check it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, stop using `ListView`. It's deprecated and second, update your `renderRow` method to render individual keys of the object instead of the complete object.

Comment: Okay! Then What is the alternative of listview?

Comment: FlatList - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist, SectionList - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in:

`renderRow={(data) => <View><Text>{data}</Text></View>}`

Data is an object and you are trying to render it. JSX cannot render objects, instead select any key of data object to construct your html.

Comment: Sorry! I didn't get this. This is exactly what I am doing

Comment: You are trying to render an object :) try replace `data` by `data.text`